# Правила именований папок и пакетов

Tags: java, best-practice

Как правильно именовать папки?
`org. ... .annotation`
или же 
`org. ... .annotationS`?

```
model / models
controller / controllers
```

Comment: имхо, как хотите - главное, чтобы в рамках одного проекта был выбран какой-то один вариант